# Prevent the TextBox from getting highlighted

Tags: c#, winforms

C# WinForms: There is a lot of code playing around SelectionStart, SelectionText, etc properties of a textbox in a program defect I am working on. The thing is that I do not want the text of this text box to get highlighted with those selectionstart, selectionLength, etc methods....Is there a way that I can say turn off selection highlight when we are manipulating the text of a text box with those properties?

Comment: If the textbox is not going to be edited, make the ReadOnly value true.

Comment: we are editing the text box. I still want all SelectionStart, SelectionLength,etc to be in place but just dont want that arewa to get highlighhted AND selected.

Comment: Set SelectionLength back to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of clumsy, but at the end of each of those event handlers you could put focus on some other object.  Maybe a textbox that's not visible on the form?